# Step-down circuitry

Tags: dc-dc-converter, esp8266, repair

I have a water-filter board that receives 36V input, and needs to power an ESP-WROOM-02D in 3.3V. The power circuit that converts from the 36V to 3.3V is no longer working, and I am trying to understand what are the different components involved. From a look at this section of the board, I see the following:

- 9971GH transistor N-channel MOSFET
- M6 transistor PNP
- M7 diode
- 4 resistors (2x 27.2kΩ, 2x 10.3kΩ?)

[image: Board power section with labels]

Now I am trying to understand why when I supply the input 36V, I have no 3.3V in the output (from the test point on the board). The basic test with a multimeter on the M7 diode seems to indicate the diode still let current flow in one direction only. Where to take it from there?

[image: The ESP to be powered.]

Adding overall view of the board front and back:

- [image: Front]
- [image: Back]

***[EDIT]** Same thing with labels (fixed vocabulary):*

- [image: with labels]

*(edit added yet more labels)*

Comment: Is there an inductor or transformer somewhere near Q5?

Comment: not as far as I can see. There is a capacitor on the other side of the board (the two soldering points visible above R25). I'll add an overall photo of the board back and front to the original post.

Comment: Geez... This board is a terrible design. I can't seem to find where the 3V3 rail is "being made" from the 36V supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U1 and D2 are probably the switching regulator, buck diode, and the ferrite cylinder "100" is probably 10µH.  Q5 is probably some external load switch.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that part. Indeed U1 is labeled "A02X" so probably a "LV2842X" step-down regulator; and D2 is "SS14" so likely a "Surface-Mount Schottky Barrier Rectifier"?

Comment: Yeah, I can just make out SS14, and that sounds plausible for the regulator.